# Do matrices have a body?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Two tools to visualize a matrix $A$ are a numerical range $W(A)$ and a Davis-Wielandt shell $DW(A)$:

$$W(A):=\{(\Re (x^*Ax),\Im(x^*Ax)) :\|x\|_2=1\}\subseteq \mathbb{C},$$

$$DW(A):=\{(x^*Ax,x^*A^*Ax) \mid x\in\mathbb{C^n},\|x\|_2=1\}\subseteq\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{R}^+.$$

As you can see $W(A)$ provides 2D image and $DW(A)$ provides 3D image. But both have some shortcomings:

1. $W(A)$ and $W(B)$ may have the same shape for different $A$ and $B$,
2. $W(A)$ and $DW(A)$ are defined for square matrices (although I found a paper that attempts to define a numerical range of rectangular matrices, it looks like not many people have accepted that definition, thus not widely used),
3. Both $W(A)$ and $DW(A)$ are not widely used for educational purposes, which is in my opinion means that not many people accept it as a matrix body. Otherwise, since matrices are used in many fields, I would expect people to study a matrix body.

I know that it maybe not logical to search whether matrices have body, because they are just arrays of numbers. But I still wonder if there are ways we can visualize them? It would be especially useful in educational purposes. Please let me know if there are different ways to visualize a matrix than $W(A)$ and $DW(A)$.

Comment: So when you “body”, do you mean some figure that represents the matrix geometrically?

Comment: yes, geometric visualization of a matrix

Comment: @Lee You wrote $W(A) \subset \Bbb C^2$. Presumably, you mean either $W(A) \subset \Bbb C$ or $W(A) \subset \Bbb R^2$.

Comment: @Lee It's not clear what advantage you believe that using $W(A)$ or $DW(A)$ as a 
"visual" representation confers. What do I get from looking at the "visualization" $W(A)$ (or $DW(A)$) that I don't get from looking at the actual matrix $A$ and its entries? Perhaps your answer to that is something like "the representation of $A$ should be the same under a unitary change of basis". If that's the case, then what information do I get from looking $W(A)$ that I don't get from looking at a list of its eigenvalues and singular values?

Comment: @BenGrossmann thanks I have corrected the mistake

Comment: @BenGrossmann for some students, including me, visual explanations are better. There might not be advantage of $W(A)$ or $DW(A)$ when studying particular matrix, but when one studies a set of matrices, for example the set of unitary, or Hermitian or normal matrices with singular value bounds, DW shell provide simple visual explanation that is very easy to explain for beginners in linear algebra. I just wonder if there was some uniformly accepted definition of a matrix "body", it would be used as an additional tool in teaching linear algebra.